# How much current can I supply to power PIC12F675?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, pic

I have a power supply that outputs 5.9V at 375mA that I'm running through a 5V regulator.

I'm wondering if 375mA is too much for a PIC12F675? I dont want to fry this little guy.

If it's too much how can I reduce it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't GIVE current to the device. The device TAKES the current depending on the equivalent impedance of the device, but in cases such as this, where you have a consumer as complicated as a microcontroller, the proper way of doing things is to read microcontroller's datasheet and see how much current it needs in various states and then make sure that your power supply is capable of providing AT LEAST that much current, but preferably more.

Also I doubt your setup will work. You'll be safer if you have a power supply that can provide higher voltage than 5.9 V. Usually it's recommended to have at least two more volts in front of the regulator. Next, you will need to take into account the regulator as well. It has it's own voltage drop which you should find in the regulator's datasheet and there you'll also find the maximum current it can supply and how much current it consumes for its own operation. Make sure that you actually read that! If you do have a regulator that can give regulated 5 V from 5.9 V input, it could happen that it can provide only very little current and that the regulator could get fried. Also don't forget that regulators need additional components to work properly and again, you'll find those in the datasheet.

If you don't want to read the datasheets (but you really really and again really should), you can watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSzVs7_aW-Y) short video which explains how linear regulators work.

Comment: Oh I see, yea the regulator in fact is only spitting out 4.5V. thanks!

Comment: Datasheets for the common 7805 regulator differ on the amount of drop required for it to work well. IIRC most specify 2V, but some do specify 3V. So unless one knows the manufacturer, better design for 3V.

Answer (score 4):

Whether it will work will depend on the type of regulator, if it's a standard linear regulator then it won't, but if it's an LDO (low dropout regulator - see below) it may be fine.
The PIC will only take as much current as it requires. A simple way to see this is that If the voltage and resistance are static, then the current must be too.

Let's simplify the internals of the PIC and say they look like a 500 ohm resistor. If the supply is at 5V, then the PIC will draw 5/500 = 10mA. It doesn't matter whether the supply is rated at 375 milliamps or 375 million amps, the PIC will still only draw 10mA. The rating you see is the maximum it can supply without it's voltage dropping significantly.

In your regulator datasheet, you should have a table like this:

[image: Dropout]

You can see the dropout voltage is 2V (there are three columns as the table is for a 5V, 12V and 15V regulator from left to right) and the input voltage required to maintain regulation is 7.5V (in the case of the 5V regulator)

There is also a graph (for the 5V version):

[image: Dropout2]

Notice how this matches with the table, the output voltage is *less than* 5V until the input voltage reaches at least 7V. The current drawn by the load will make a slight difference too.

This example regulator (a 7805) would *not* work with your setup, but something like the LM2937 (just the first 5V LDO I found on google) would work as it has a dropout voltage of 0.5V at room temperature (so you need more than 5.5V in, which you have)
Note that this (particular LDO) would not be ideal (depending on what conditions you will use it under) as over the full temperature range the dropout voltage can increase to 1V, and you would lose regulation.

Comment: Gotcha, its a normal linear regulator and didn't work when I tried it. But thanks, I know what to do now!